# RepaintManager that animates damaged regions of components?

Tags: java, swing, repaintmanager

I'm looking for a existing class i remember seeing, but can't remember the name.

It animated the dirty paint regions used by RepaintManager to update JComponents.

It was done by extending RepaintManager i think.

Comment: here you can start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787998/how-to-generate-exceptions-from-repaintmanager

Comment: @mKorbel: Perhaps [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614972/passing-current-date/8616169#8616169)?

Comment: Nope. It's actually this: http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/swinglabs/jxlayer/3.0.4/jxlayer-3.0.4-javadoc.jar!/org/jdesktop/jxlayer/plaf/ext/DebugRepaintingUI.html

Answer (score 1):

I found it:
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/alexfromsun/archive/2007/11/debug_swing_rep.html

Edit: the code needs download from here https://svn.java.net/svn/jxlayer~svn  and compile. The Class is DebugRepaintingUI.