# JViewport.BACKINGSTORE_SCROLL_MODE and setOpaque(false)

Tags: java, swing, scroll, transparent

I have a transparency/scrolling problem with my scroll pane. As far as I can tell, the docs do not address this behavior.

Here's is the code for my transparent text pane:

```
    textArea.setOpaque(false);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);
    scrollPane.setViewportBorder(border);
    scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
    //scrollPane.getViewport().setScrollMode(JViewport.BACKINGSTORE_SCROLL_MODE);
    scrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
```

This works fine, except the scrolling is very sluggish. When the `setScrollMode` line is uncommented, the scrolling is much more responsive but the transparency is lost.

Is there any way I can get into a win-win situation?

EDIT: Okay, the original question isn't really answered, but I did find out that the cause was actually a call to `javax.swing.UIManager.put("TabbedPane.font", someCustomFont)`. I left out this detail because I thought it was irrelevant.. who would have thought. I don't know why this results in sluggish scrolling, but I'm just glad to have found the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1) `JViewport` is by default `traslucent/transparent`,

2) required set follows methods for `JViewpot`

```
JViewport.setScrollMode(JViewport.BLIT_SCROLL_MODE);
JViewport.setScrollMode(JViewport.BACKINGSTORE_SCROLL_MODE);
JViewport.setScrollMode(JViewport.SIMPLE_SCROLL_MODE);
```

3) simple example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614972/passing-current-date), without any freeeze or jumping during the scrolling

Comment: 1) Not from my findings? If I don't call `scrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false)`, the whole thing is messed up?
2/3) Wouldn't calling all three at once just result in the last one called being used?

Comment: important is there, what's Object did you put to the JViewport or JTextArea,

Comment: The view is only a simple default 600x500 JTextPane with 2 full views of text. I am not overriding the paint method of the viewport and I have no need to.

I do not have an explanation for the behavior, and wouldn't mind one compared to answers with code similar to that shown in my question.

Comment: I've posted one. In the example, you might be able to see that when you drag the scrollbar thumb, it's very sluggish. This gets worse when more text is added.

When the scroll mode is changed, the sluggishness abates, but the viewport (guessing) is no longer transparent.

Comment: these methods are for Object added to the JViewport, really never need to solved that why one of them (if is alone) freeze JScrollPane's content not what's and for why sombody implements for JTable `Draws viewport contents into an offscreen image.` simple doesn't works for JTextArea