# JComponents does not show up on the screen with enabled double buffering

Tags: java, swing, paint, jtextcomponent

I am writing a 2D game with Swing. For the menu I use JButtons and now I want to use a JPasswordField. The problem is: If I try to write something in it, the programme crashes.
I located the error to this single line of code:

```
frame.getLayeredPane().paintComponents(graphics);
```

The password field is not painted properly and the programme crashes. But if I don't use this line, no component does show up. I think this is because I use double buffering, but I need this for the game itself.

The JFrame is created here:

```
public void createFrame() {
    RepaintManager.setCurrentManager(new RepaintManager() {
        @Override
        public void addDirtyRegion(final JComponent c, final int x, final int y, final int w, final int h) {}
        @Override
        public void addInvalidComponent(final JComponent invalidComponent) {}
        @Override
        public void markCompletelyDirty(final JComponent aComponent) {}
        @Override
        public void paintDirtyRegions() {} 
    });

    frame = new JFrame("Bubble Trouble");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    maximizeFrame(getFirstCompatibleMode(displayModes));
    //setFullScreen(getFirstCompatibleMode(displayModes));
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    ((JComponent) frame.getContentPane()).setOpaque(false);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    main.getComponentHandler().initComponents(panel);
    main.getKeyHandler().registerKeys(main.getComponentHandler().getPanel());
    panel.setOpaque(false);
    panel.addMouseListener(main.getMouseListener());

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

    frame.createBufferStrategy(2);
}
```

This method is called to repaint and so refresh the game:

```
public void draw() {
    Graphics graphics = null;
    JFrame frame = screenHandler.getFrame();
    BufferStrategy bufferStrategy = frame.getBufferStrategy();
    try {

        graphics = (Graphics) bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();

        switch(main.getStatus()) {
            case MENU_MAIN:     drawMainMenu(graphics); break;
            case MENU_GAME:     drawGameMenu(graphics); break;
            case GAME:          drawGame(graphics); break;
            case LEVELCHANGE:   drawLevelChange(graphics); break;
            case SCORE:         drawScore(graphics); break;
        }
        drawHertz(graphics);

        graphics.translate(frame.getInsets().left, frame.getInsets().top);
        frame.getLayeredPane().paintComponents(graphics);

        if (!bufferStrategy.contentsLost())
            bufferStrategy.show();

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {} 
    finally {
        if (graphics != null) graphics.dispose();
    }

    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();

    Thread.yield();
}
```

Comment: I hope draw() is executed on [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

Comment: Are you _sure_ you need double buffering? `JPanel` has enabled this by default, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8616169/230513).

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).