# Draw A Tree Data Structure in Java

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

Given a tree how one could approach to draw the same using Java Swing that what we draw in a simple piece of paper to understand a tree ? i.e. drawing all the nodes an values inside the node circle as well as threads to join the parents with the child and so on .The Structure will be like this :

[image]

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29#/media/File:Binary_tree.svg

Comment: As an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455739/animate-change-of-color-of-nodes-in-insertion-of-binary-search-tree/15458451#15458451)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JavaFX` for that:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm

That's the newest Java GUI technology!

Comment: Here is the same in Swing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126695/how-to-draw-a-tree-representing-a-graph-of-connected-nodes

Comment: Can  you mention any tutorial or like that?

Comment: I've read an book. But in German. ;) So I unfortunately don't know a good online tutorial. sorry

Comment: Given the [tag:swing] tag, the suggestion of Java-FX is off topic and irrelevant. Swing will be around for a long time yet.