# Draw Stanford sentiment treebank in java

Tags: java, swing, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm using Stanford coreNLP for sentiment analytics.
Now I want visualization the tree bank look like http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/treebank.html

But I can't get score for each node in the treebank, so I can't do it.
I had found in the internet and seen somebody can draw easy in Python.

Do you have any idea to draw the treebank for Stanford sentiment in java (swing is an example).

Thanks all.

Comment: Maybe have a look at JavaFX?

Comment: [Heres a very basic example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455739/animate-change-of-color-of-nodes-in-insertion-of-binary-search-tree/15458451#15458451), but if you do some research, there are several libraries around which can produce the graphs you're trying to generate

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer, I can draw the parse tree in Swing but I can't get score for each node in tree, do you know how to get score for each node in Stanford parse tree of sentiment?