# How to draw star in java swing using fillPolygon

Tags: java, swing, java-2d, shapes

I'm having trouble setting the coordinate of the star are there any better solution for this. I cannot get the the correct shape. Can someone help me on this?

```
  public void star(Graphics shapes)
{
    shapes.setColor(color);
    int[] x  = {42,52,72,52,60,40,15,28,9,32,42};
    int [] y = {38,62,68,80,105,85,102,75,58,20,38};
    shapes.fillPolygon(x, y, 5);
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I'd use the [2D Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) shapes API, they allow you to "draw" a shape, which is simpler (IMHO) then using polygon. The advantage is, they are easy to paint and transform

Comment: I find this question is more about math than programming.

Answer (score 2):

Sun's implementation provides some custom Java 2D shapes like `Rectangle`, `Oval`, `Polygon` etc. but it's not enough. There are GUIs which require more custom shapes like `Regular Polygon`, `Star` and `Regular polygon` with rounded corners. The project provides some more shapes often used. All the classes implements `Shape` interface which allows user to use all the usual methods of `Graphics2D` like `fill()`, `draw()`, and create own shapes by combining them.

[Regular Polygon Star](http://java-sl.com/shapes.html)

**Edit:**

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327588/how-to-make-star-shape-in-java)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: but still cannot get the perfect 5 star.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I'd use the [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) shapes API, they allow you to "draw" a shape, which is simpler (IMHO) then using polygon. The advantage is, they are easy to paint and transform

Having said that, the problem you're actually having is the fact that you're not passing the right information to the `fillPolygon` method.

If you take a look at the [JavaDocs for `Graphics#fillPolygon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillPolygon(int[],%20int[],%20int)), you'll note that the last parameter is the number of points:

> nPoints - a the total number of points.

But you're passing `5`, where there are actually `11` points in your array

Something like...

```
shapes.setColor(color);
int[] x  = {42,52,72,52,60,40,15,28,9,32,42};
int [] y = {38,62,68,80,105,85,102,75,58,20,38};
shapes.fillPolygon(x, y, 11);
```

should now draw all the points, but some of your coordinates are slightly off, so you might want to check that

Comment: Thank you also for the references so much helpful

Answer (score 1):

The second to last number of your Y should be 60 not 20

```
g2.setColor(color);
int[] x  = {42,52,72,52,60,40,15,28,9,32,42};
int[] y = {38,62,68,80,105,85,102,75,58,60,38};
g2.fillPolygon(x , y, 11);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having trouble setting the coordinate of the star are there any better solution for this

Check out [Playing With Shapes](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/). You should be able to use the `ShapeUtils` class to generate your shape.

This class will generate the points for you so you don't need to manage every pixel.

Answer (score 0):

a star has 10 points ppl mind that not 11

```
setBackground(Color.black);  
    int[]x={250,150,0,150,100,250,400,350,500,350};
    int[]y={100,200,200,300,400,300,400,300,200,200};
    g.fillPolygon( (x),(y),10);         
    setForeground(Color.cyan);
```

this will help to draw a star with black bg and cyan foreground