# Java JFrame rectangle

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint

So, I've been learning Java and I'm still pretty new, so bear with me. My latest goal is graphical programs, and this one is a test on keyboard control. For some reason, this program won't display a rectangle. Normally paint() runs on its own, but for some reason it isn't. I've looked at other programs that I made that work, and others on the web, and I still can't figure it out.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class App extends JFrame{

    public static int keyVal = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App();   
        while(true){
            System.out.println(keyVal);
            Wait.ms(50);
        }
    }

    public App(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setTitle("Pong");
        f.setSize(300,400);

        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        f.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
                keyVal = e.getKeyCode();
            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
                keyVal = 0;
            }

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
        });

        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        while(true){
            g.drawRect(20, 20, 100, 60);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: step 1 - never put a `while(true)` in your `paint` function - it'll never finish, and your UI will lock up.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Although sadly it still doesn't work. :/

Comment: Sorry, haven't had time to look into this further - I scanned through it and noticed the glaring issue, and figured I could be at least a little helpful, even if I didn't solve the problem.

Comment: [This tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step1.html) will step you through creating an example Swing app - you should be able to take the lessons learned and apply it to your app. Some other differences I've noticed - override `paintComponent` instead of `paint`, and don't use `Wait` in your `main` function.  If someone else wants to pattern your app after the code samples there and post it as an answer, be my guest...

Answer (score 2):

1. One don't paint on top-level containers like `JFrame` as they already carry the load of painting components and aren't double buffered.
2. Instead use a custom `JPanel` to paint and override its `paintComponent` method and call `super.paintCompoent`. Then add that panel to the frame.

   ```
   public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
       @Override 
       protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
           super.paintComponent(g);
       }

       @Override
       public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
           return new Dimension(300, 300);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Also notice in the code above, I overrode the `getPreferredSize()` method. This is what you want to do when painting on a `JPanel`. The reason is that there is no set preferred size, so you'll want to set it. Also this should be used so you don't have to set a size the frame that holds it. Instead just call `frame.pack()` and the preferred size of the `JPanel` will be respected.
4. Don't use `KeyListener` with Swing apps. Instead use [**Key Bindings**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), and you may face focus issues, among others, using `KeyListener`. You can see an example [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20844242/2587435) on how to use a simple key bind.
5. Also you should run your Swing apps from the **Event Dispatch Thread** like this

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
           @Override
           public void run() {
               new MyApp();
           }
       });
   }
   ```
6. Don't use `while` in your `paintComponent` methods. You will run into problems. If you want something to be drawing repeatedly, like animation, you will want to look into using a `javax.swing.Timer`. You can see an example [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21298119/2587435) or an any number of SO post you can find just doing a simple search of how to use a Swing Timer.
7. Also, Your `App` class is already a `JFrame` sublcass. There's no need to create another `JFrame` in the constructor. Just add the components to it, something like this

   ```
   public App() {
       add(new MyPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
       add(new JButton("Button"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   }
   ```